# How to change font information such that XeTeX selects the correct face of the font family?

Tags: fonts, xetex, opentype

I am revising the Fetamont fonts and I am faced with a unsolved problem related to XeLaTeX (or maybe fontspec):

I have put all the OpenType font faces in the local font folder (so XeLaTeX is able to find them by font name). If the following source file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Fetamont}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

is compiled with XeLaTeX (3.14159265-2.6-0.99996) it will set "Test" in the condensed face. How can I change the font information inside the *.otf of the various faces such that XeLaTeX (without adding a Fetamont.fontspec file) will choose the regular face instead?

(Changing the alphabetic order of the otf files is not a suitable solution. Changing the source file is not a suitable solution.)

Comment: Have you tried using "Fetamont Regular" (or please add some more information about the setup)? Have you tried addressing them by file name?

Comment: @TeXnician I don't want to change the source file, so "Fetamont Regular" or calling them by file name is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the names for the 10pt version to

> ```
> Family:              Fetamont
> Subfamily:           Regular
> Full name:           Fetamont Regular 
> PostScript name:     Fetamont-Regular
> ```

will find this version as the default regular. And the same for the bold
version. With Bold10 it uses the heavy version instead of bold.

Comment: Removing the number 10 from the font name made it work. Thank you very much! You also mentioned the bold/heavy problem. This is still not solved by removing the number 10 from the bold font name (irrespective of leaving or removing the "10" for the heavy face).

Comment: Also a problem with the font names. However, I would prefer "readable" font names: `Fetamont-Regular.otf`, `Fetamont-Bold.otf`, `Fetamont-BoldItalic.otf`, `Fetamont-ExtraBold.otf`,   a.s.o.

Comment: "Readable" file names are okay for me, but XeLaTeX does not seem to care (as far as I tested). If I remove the light faces from the local font folder, the bold face is chosen correctly. Magic...

Comment: You should define different font families for `Fetamont`, `Fetamont Condensed`, and `Fetamont Heavy`. Then it should be easier to detect all fonts automatically by `fontconfig` or `luaotfload`.  Readable fontnames are not really readed but useful  for the user if he/she wants to see what font files are present.

Comment: I do not want to make too much families, because I have already "normal" Fetamont and Fetamont Script. Still, I will make the OpenType file names "readable" as you suggested. Meanwhile, I have also found the solution for the bold/heavy problem: Changing the os2-weight of the regular faces from "500 Medium" to "400 Regular".

Comment: yes, that all makes sense ...